# Javascript - cookies, is there a way to write a cookie for all browser at once?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, cookies, safari

Step 1: My client from his OSX/Windows comes to my site using Google chrome , and downloads a trial key such as: `LICENSE.cert` file, which contains some unique keys: `xyz-zsd-cdfd-xfdfd-1212`

Step 2: i have a cookie written (for Step 1)

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Step 3: NEXT day or Day after, again he comes back to the same site but this time he came from Safari or Firefox or IE (not using same Google chrome)

How do i read the cookie which was stored on his Google chrome in day 1? (is there anyway to write once for all? so that i suggest him?)

Comment: Each browser has its own cookie storage, and they don't know each other. The only type of cookie that could potentially work for all browsers is a flash cookie (using adobe flash) or maybe a silverlight cookie (if there is something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are managed separately by each browser - it isn't possible for you to access cookies created by other browser.

Your best bet would probably to persist the required data into some kind of database and access it when needed, if that's possible in your case.